# Print image to cups-pdf without rescaling

Tags: printing, cups

If I print a png file to a cups-pdf printer, using lp, the pic is adjusted to the page size (i'm assuming), even though fitplot is false.

> lp ~/Pictures/tux-db.png

Here is output of lpoptions:

> copies=1 device-uri=cups-pdf:/ finishings=3 fitplot=false job-hold-until=no-hold job-priority=50 job-sheets=none,none marker-change-time=0 mirror=false number-up=1 orientation-requested=3 ppd-timestamp=* printer-commands=AutoConfigure,Clean,PrintSelfTestPage printer-info=PDF printer-is-accepting-jobs=true printer-is-colormanaged=true printer-make-and-model='Generic CUPS-PDF Printer' printer-state=3 printer-state-change-time=1464004024 printer-state-reasons=none printer-type=8450124 printer-uri-supported=ipp://localhost:631/printers/PDF scaling=100

The generated pdf is [here](http://www.megafileupload.com/nzLY/tux-db.pdf).

If I open the png file with Image Viewer, and print it, I get a correct size pdf (small picture), so the printer is capable of printing the correct size. Pdf file [here](http://www.megafileupload.com/nzM2/tux-db_2.pdf).

What is the right option to use?

Using ubuntu 14.04.

Just to clear, the final goal is to use cups API in my own sw, with the correct option, so I can print images without rescaling (to avoid resizing small images to large sizes).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the answer is the scaling parameter. I thought the parameter was relative to the image, but turns out it is relative to the page.

So setting scaling=0 will print the image on its native size. 
It is possible to also manipulate it using the ppi (pixel per inch), and the natural-scaling parameter. 
More info [here](http://www.it.uu.se/datordrift/maskinpark/skrivare/cups/).